# window.sessionStorage.getItem('anyItem') is vunerable to Client DOM Stored Code Injection

Tags: javascript, xss

I have this code in my javascript file. I had run the checkMarx tool on my project and it is showing me this

> Client_DOM_Stored_Code_Injection security issue

on the `window.sessionStorage.getItem('anyItem')` code. Anyone has any clue how to resolve this issue.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: It depends where you're using the value - retrieving it into a variable isn't a problem in itself.

Answer (score 1):

I guess it's because any value can be stored in the localStorage, meaning an "evil" stringified code could be stored and thus executed (with eval for example) when retrieved. Read [this](https://www.owasp.org/index.php/Test_Local_Storage_(OTG-CLIENT-012)), it might helps you, there is an example on **XSS in localStorage**.

Other helpful link : [How secure is localstorage?](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/74155/how-secure-is-localstorage)

<s>If you app store something in the localStorage with `myKey` as key for example, any other site can override it by storing the same key. So if you rely on reading a value from a key you defined, you can't be 100% sure it will contain a value you (meaning your code) stored.</s>

**False**, see [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/de/docs/Web/API/Storage) Thanks to @Nils

To prevent (or try at least) this kind of attack, you should create a function where every value set in/retrieved from the localStorage are first evaluated to check if it contains code that could be harmful.

Also, use **[use_strict](https://developer.mozilla.org/fr/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Strict_mode)** in your code, it can be useful to prevent such things, but it still can be passed by.

**Edit**

Based on the @SilverlightFox idea, I've reached [this](https://www.owasp.org/index.php/XSS_(Cross_Site_Scripting)_Prevention_Cheat_Sheet) and found it interesting.

Comment: "any other site can override it by storing the same key" – that is simply not true. sessionStorage (and LocalStorage) are domain specific. It's in the first sentence on MDN: https://developer.mozilla.org/de/docs/Web/API/Storage

Comment: Searching for "evil" code is never going to work. There are so many ways to obfuscate it that you would never catch all occurrences. A better approach is to correctly encode when outputting data.

Answer (score 1):

A better (modern) solution to prevent code injections and XSS is CSP (Content Security Policy).
I did not tested it with local/sessionStorage, but it worths a try.

More info here: http://content-security-policy.com/
The only downside is its browser support (no IE support).